# Problem loading expl3 in plain TeX

Tags: expl3

I try to use `expl3` in plain TeX with the code:

```
\input expl3-generic %
Some text
\bye
```

I have en error message with all engines. For example, with `pdftex`:

```
! I can't find file `l3backendpdfmode.def'
```

I suspect an hyphen to be lacking in `expl3-generic.tex` (date 2019-07-01), line 89.

Comment: There is a hyphen missing in the file. It should look for l3backend-pdfmode.def.

Answer (score 13):

Yes, there is a missing `-` here. We have a fix in-hand in the development version: this is likely reasonably urgent, and I will arrange a CTAN release later today.